# Amlogic Video Crash (Kernel Oops) - Exoplayer

Tags: android, kernel, exoplayer

I'm trying to investigate where playing video on Amlogic S912 SoC can occasionally crash the kernel with a memory allocation error.  Our manufacturer is having trouble locating the issue, and I thought I'd drop it here for some feedback.

[Kernel Oops PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/sav6bwJt)

```
[29200.584083@2] H264 sysinfo: 1920x1080 duration=3200, pts_outside=1, sync_outside=0, use_idr_framerate=0
[29200.596557@2] vh264_init, vaddr=ffffffc0531a9000 phy_addr=00000000531a9000
[29200.600392@2] codec:vfm map vdec-map-0 created
[29200.604622@2] ionvid: info: reg:ionvideo
[29200.608576@2] codec:vdec_init, vf_provider_name = vdec.h264.00
[29200.614810@2] ionvid: info: ionvideo open
[29200.618430@2] ionvid: info: ionvideo: set freerun mode
[29200.657498@7] 0: AV_SCRATCH_1 = 841fe078, AV_SCRATCH_2 18063
[29200.657747@7] 0: frame_mbs_only_flag 1, crop_bottom 4,  frame_height 1080, 0: mb_height 68,crop_right 0, frame_width 1920, mb_width 120
[29200.669930@7] 0: mb height/widht/total: 44/78/1fe0 level_idc 28 max_ref_num 4
[29200.677095@7] 0: vh264_set_params active_buf_spec_num 11 reorder_pic_num 5 collocate_buf_num 8
[29200.685629@0] 0: num_ref_frames change from 0 to 4
[29200.799343@4] alloc_fd: slot 140 not NULL!
[29200.799591@5] alloc_fd: slot 142 not NULL!
[29200.799813@6] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ffffffbe23876f28
[29200.799816@6] pgd = ffffffc084730000
[29200.799827@6] [ffffffbe23876f28] *pgd=0000000000000000
[29200.799839@6] Internal error: Oops: 96000005 [#1] PREEMPT SMP
```

We're simply playing full screen videos in a loop using ExoPlayer on Android, and usually get a full kernel panic regarding what appears to be the h264 decoder.

Would appreciate anyone knowledgeable with kernels to confirm our understanding of the issue and hopefully determine where we should be looking to resolve the issue.

Android 7.1
Kernel 3.24.29
Amlogic S912 SoC

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow isn't a support site for a 3d-party software.

Comment: The issue isn't the third party ExoPlayer, it occurs with VideoView as well, I only mentioned it to provide a full picture.

Comment: Well, the problem is actually with a kernel or with one of its drivers (a user-space software shouldn't trigger bugs in the kernel). But again, Stack Overflow **isn't a support site** for them.

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts.  I'm honestly having a difficult time determining where this should be posted, if not here.